# How to find multiple elements on headless browser and click them after a timeout

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, zombie.js, node-horseman

I want to detect elements in the DOM without a specific child, and then click the ones without the child after a timeout. There is no way to explicitly and directly find the elements only get all elements with a certain class, and omit the ones with a specific child class.

Let's say the browser has this code:

```
<div class="card">
  <div></div>
  <button>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div></div>
  <button>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="dont-click"></div>
  <button>
</div>
```

The following code works in casperjs/horseman, basically gets all elements with the `.card` class then looks for elements where a child has the `.dont-click` class and omits it:

```
  var cards = $('.card');
  var listOfClickables = cards.filter(function(i, card) {
    var jCard = $(card);
    var found = jCard.find('.dont-click');
    if (found.length <= 0) {
      return jCard;
    }
  });

  return listOfClickables;
```

This works, now I want to go through this list, one by one, and click the child button of each `.card`. This code works if you copy and paste into the browser:

```
recursiveFunction(listOfClickables);
function recursiveFunction(list){
  var jCard = list.shift();
  $(jCard).find('button').click();

  var delayMs = Math.random() * 5;

  setTimeout(function() {
    recursiveFunction(list);
  }, delayMs * 1000);
}
```

It takes the list from the previous function, and recursively clicks the child button, waits a bit, and then pops the next element until the list is empty.

I tried to click just a single one of these items but I'm running into some problems:

1. Seems like everything must be done in the `.evaluate()` block, you can't return a list of jquery elements, and then pass it into another `.evaluate()` block
2. Seems like you can't click the element using a `jQuery.click('.card button')`, you'd have to somehow identify it outside of the `.evaluate()` block, and then use the `.click()` method from casperjs/horseman.

Is it possible to use these frameworks to do something like a "find all elements with this selector, and then go through these elements and return the ones without a child element with class `.dont-click`, then click all the returned elements' child buttons"?

Comment: If you use a recent enough PhantomJS (2.1+) you can click() elements natively inside of `page.evaluate()`. Like `jQuery(".js-add-link")[0].click()`

Comment: Does it handle async well? Like if I did the `.click()`, waited a bit, then did it again in a recursive function?

Comment: There is a way to select those: `$('.card:not(:has(.dont-click))')`

Comment: Your own recursive function is quite fine. I'm just saying that you can try to do everything in one `page.evaluate`.

Comment: @pgardiario: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has looks like experimental. Not sure if it's going to be stable

Comment: @Vaviloff: thanks. I'll try to just use phantomjs then